# Match a multiline string starting and ending with the same unknown character

Tags: python, regex

Regex to match a multiline string starting with 'banner  ............... ' where x is picked up from the regex itself

```
r'banner (\^|\$)(.*\n)*(\^|\$)'
```

will help with 'banner ^ ........ ^' or 'banner $ ....... $' but what if I don't know what this character is and want it to be the character right after 'banner'

I have a workaround where I capture this unknown character and then use it in a second regex, but is there any possibility or a better way of doing it.

Sample text

```
banner ^

------ WARNING  ---------------------------------------------------------
This equipment is the property of XYZ.
Any unauthorised connection attempt is prohibited and will result
in criminal prosecution under applicable criminal laws.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
^
```

or

```
banner $
      _____________________________
     | Unauthorized access to this |
     | system is forbidden and     |
     | subject to prosecution.     |
     | All actions performed on    |
     | this device are logged.     |
      -----------------------------
 .       .
 \`-"'"-'/
  } 6 6 {
 =.  Y  ,=
   /^^^\  .
  /     \  )
 (  )-(  )/
  ""   ""
$
```

But keep in mind the character $ / ^ is unknown
Cheers

Comment: Provide examples of the example strings you want to capture.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\bbanner (\S)[\s\S]*?\1` https://regex101.com/r/OO5DhD/1

Comment: Yes @Thefourthbird I wanted to know how to use match groups within the same Regex expression without having to find the match group and use it in other expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [backreferences](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Try this:

```
r'banner (\S)(.*\n)*(\1)'
```

Where `\1` is a backreference to the first capturing group. `\S` will match anything other than whitespace. If you only want to match symbols, you can use `[^\w\s]` instead of `\S`.

However, this regex does not match your sample of `banner ^ ........ ^` because that string does not contain a newline. If you want to match any combination of characters or newlines, rather than absolutely requiring a newline, you can use:

```
r'banner (\S)[\s\S]*(\1)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/STZegD/2)

Answer (score 1):

If the value should be at the start of the last sentence, you can match banner followed by all the lines that do not start with the value of the backreference.

You can capture the first non whitespace char after banner in a capturing group and use a backreference to that captured value using `\1`

This will prevent unnecessary backtracking instead of using `(.*\n)*` or `[\s\S]*?`

```
\bbanner (\S).*(?:\r?\n(?!\1).*)*\r?\n\1
```

**Explanation**

- `\bbanner (\S)` Match banner, space and capture a non whitespace char in **group 1**
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!\1).*` Match a newline if it does not start with the captured value
- `)*` Close the group and repeat it 0+ times
- `\r?\n\1` Match a newline followed by the captured value

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPk8se/1)

---

If the value should be a single value at the start of the line and a single value on the line for the last match:

```
^banner (\S)(?:\r?\n(?!\1).*)*\r?\n\1$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vm01fm/1)